# Cypress test: is .contains() equivalent to should('contain')?

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

Is this: `cy.get('[name=planSelect]').contains(dummyPlan)`

equivalent to this: `cy.get('[name=planSelect]').should('contain', dummyPlan)`

And if so, which is preferred? The first is more of an implicit assertion, but it's shorter and cleaner to my mind.

**Follow-up question:** After looking around to see how best to select elements for e2e testing I found that the [Cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Selecting-Elements) recommend using `data-cy` attributes. Is there a reason this would be better than just adding `name` attributes to the markup? Should `name` only be used for forms fields?

Comment: I recommend to use contains after get then verify existence with should
cy.get('[name=planSelect]').contains(dummyPlan, {matchCase: false}).should('exist')

Comment: @PedroMachado This what you suggest, to check existence at the end is not necessary. Because cy.get() and cy.contains() has build-in existence assertion. Please see https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Assertions

Comment: This should be two separate questions. `contains()` and `should("contain")` is distinct from `data-cy` attribute best practices.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The result on your cypress test will be the same if the element with `name=planSelect` does not contain `dummyPlan`, that is, the test will fail at this point.

The difference between them is that in the first form, using [contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#), you're actually trying to select an element, and the result of cy.get(...).contains() will yield this expected DOM element, allowing for further chaining of methods, like:

```
cy.get('[name=planSelect]').contains(dummyPlan).click();
```

In the second form you are making an explicit assertion to verify that dummyPlan exists within the other element, using the [Chai](http://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) chainer `contain`.

It is a subtle difference and the result is the same, but I would recommend you to use `cy.get('[name=planSelect]').contains(dummyPlan)` only in case you would like to chain some other method after contains, and use the second form if you want to explicitly assert that this element exists. Logically speaking, the first would represent a generic test failure (cypress tried to find an element that wasn't there) and the second represents an explicit assertion failure (element should contain `dummyPlan` but it does not).

As for your second question, `name` is a valid HTML attribute and using it for your tests can lead to confusion if the attribute is being used in its original function (to name input fields) or if the attribute is there just for testing purposes. I would recommend you to use `cy-name` as the documentation suggests because this way you avoid this ambiguity and make it clear that this attribute `cy-name` is only there for testing purposes.

Furhtermore, on some situations you might decide to strip all `cy-name` from your code before sending it to production (during the build process, using some webpack plugin, like [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader)). You would not be able to do the same if using just `name` because you would also remove the required input `name`, if there was some inputs in your code.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I get what you mean about a generic vs explicit failure, and agree with you, so thanks for helping to clarify that!

Comment: Cypress actually [advises](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements) using a data element for targeting an element `data-cy="someName"`.

Comment: I would add to this answer that .contains() is a query method. 
.should("contain") is the assertion.

Answer (score 5):

### Answer

- `.contains(selector, content)` is the best selector; it retries
  element selection **AND** allows text matching (not just `<tag>`
  `.class` `#id` `[attributes]`)
- `.should()` is just an assertion and only the assertion is retried
  (not the element selection)

`.should('exist')` is implied unless you specify your own -- this is how they allowed `.should('not.exist')`

---

### Tangent

Browsers support XPath 1.0 which is a pretty cool but obscure way to make complex queries based on DOM tree traversal. There's a [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) predicate function:

```
//*[         contains(normalize-space(.), 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.') ]
   [not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(.), 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.') ])]
```

This searches from root of the document for any node that contains the text and doesn't contain a descendant node which contains the text.

You can test it in the console with the Chrome `$x()` shortcut or this polyfill (and helper):

```
getLowestDomNodesByText("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.")

function getLowestDomNodesByText (text) {
  return x(`//*[contains(normalize-space(.), '${text}')][not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(.), '${text}') ])]`);
};

function x (expression) {
  const results = new XPathEvaluator().evaluate(expression, document);

  const nodes = [];
  let node = null;
  while (node = results.iterateNext()) {
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  return nodes;
}
```

If you need even more performance, you can use a TreeWalker with `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT` as seen in this [chrome extension](https://github.com/neaumusic/selection-highlighter/blob/master/src/highlighter/highlighter.js) I've worked on for a long time

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to use contains after get then verify existence with should.

```
cy.get('[name=planSelect]').contains(dummyPlan, {matchCase: false}).should('exist')
```