# How to get 2nd div of the same class with Cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a chatbot application which I want to test it with Cypress. I'm looking at the case if the bot has responded to client correctly. So I check after click I should get a div which has class **bot-message**.

```js
cy.get('.bot-message').should('have.text','I want to send invoice to my email')
```

```js
CypressError: Timed out retrying: expected
[ <div.bot-message>, 3 more... ] to have text 
I want to send invoice to my email. , but the text was 
I want to see my profile.I want to see my invoices.
I want to send invoice to my email
```

The problem here is that cypress gets all the divs within a class named **bot-message**.

So what I want to be able to do is to say get the 3rd div of the same class. If that is not the case then I think I should give data attributes to every bot message div

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the `eq` to get A DOM element at a specific index in an array of elements.

From [API docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html#Index):

> The querying behavior of this command matches exactly how .eq() works in jQuery. Its behavior is also similar to that of the CSS pseudo-class :nth-child() selector.

```
cy.get('.bot-message')
  .eq(1) // to get 2nd element. array index (counting) starts from 0
  .should('have.text','I want to send invoice to my email');
```

Comment: Yes, eq(number) is what I was looking for, not it expects 1 element instead of all possible elements

Answer (score 0):

What about `contains` ?

```
cy.get('.bot-message').contains('I want to send invoice to my email')
```

Comment: While `.contains()` works here and implicitly tests this, it is not an assertion which is what the question is looking for.  Here's another answer that explains the difference well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50049358/2883129