# Asserting a DOM element if it has a specific text

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm starting out in Cypress, I'm trying to select an element with this text:

*Username is missing*

My code is:

```
cy.get('[data-id="error"]').should('have.text', 'is missing')
```

Is there a way that I can just use a specific part of a string (in this case, 'is missing') and still be able to use the `.should()` assertion? I hope to pass the assertion using specific part of a string only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression with `match` instead of `have.text`:

For example the text should contain `test`:

```
cy.get('[data-id="error"]').should('match', /test/)
```

Or simply

```
cy.get('[data-id="error"]').should('contain', 'test')
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use contain keyword to look string that contain a substring

with should to perform directly the assertion

```
cy.get('[data-id="error"]').should('contain', 'is missing')
```

or get only element that contain text with contains

```
cy.get('[data-id="error"]').contains('is missing')
```

them perform needed assertion on it

Comment: please note that `contains` is not the same as `should` ... it returns an element, doesn't check if it exists ... a bit different thing, you can read more about it in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042670/cypress-test-is-contains-equivalent-to-shouldcontain

Comment: ***returns an element, doesn't check if it exists*** does not make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assert an partial text with `should` then you can use `include.text`

```js
cy.get('[data-id="error"]').should('include.text', 'is missing')
```